# What does difficulty mean in PoA and PoS chains?

Tags: polygon, consensus, binance-smart-chain, difficulty, fantom

In PoW, the meaning of "difficulty" is quite straightforward and, for instance, fully described in yellow paper. (https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)

**But what does the "difficulty" field mean in chains with the following consensus protocols:**

1. PoA
2. PoS

For instance:
https://polygonscan.com/block/27364484 - difficulty = 20
https://bscscan.com/block/17112074 - difficulty = 2
https://ftmscan.com/block/36539487 - difficulty = 0
https://blockscout.com/xdai/mainnet/block/21736203/transactions - difficulty = 340,282,366,920......